# Python: cycling/scanning though fields in an object

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file named MyFile.json that contains this structure:

```
[{u'randomName1': {u'A': 16,u'B': 20,u'C': 71},u'randomName2': {u'A': 12,u'B': 17,u'C': 47}},...]
```

I can open the file and load it like this:

```
import json

with open('MyFile.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
```

And I can access the values in the first element like this:

```
data[0]["randomName1"][A]
data[0]["randomName1"][B]
data[0]["randomName1"][C]

data[0]["randomName2"][A]
data[0]["randomName2"][B]
data[0]["randomName2"][C]
```

The A B C keys are always named A B C (and there are always exactly 3 of them, so that's no problem.

The problem is:
1) I don't know how many elements are in the list, and
2) I don't know how many "randomName" keys are in each element, and
3) I don't know the names of the randomName keys.

How do I scan/cycle through the entire file, getting all the elements, and getting all the key names and associated key values for each element?

I don't have the knowledge or desire to write a complicated parsing script of my own.  I was expecting that there's a way for the json library to provide this information.

For example (and this is not a perfect analogy I realize) if I am given an array X in AWK, I can scan all the index/name pairs by using

```
for(index in X){print index, X[index]);
```

Is there something like this in Python?

---------------- New info below this line  -------------

Thank you Padraic and E.Gordon. That goes a long way toward solving the problem.

In an attempt to make my initial post as concise as possible, I simplified my JSON data example too much.

My JSON data actually looks this this:

```
data=[
{ {u'X': u'randomName1': {u'A': 11,u'B': 12,u'C': 13}, u'randomName2': {u'A': 21,u'B': 22,u'C': 23}, ... }, u'Y': 101, u'Z': 102 },
.
.
.
]
```

The ellipses represent arbitrary repetition, as described in the original post.  The X Y Z keys are always named X Y Z (and there are always exactly 3 of them).

Using your posts as a starting point, I've been working on this for a couple of hours, but being new to Python I'm stumped.  I cannot figure out how to add the extra loop to work with that data.  I would like the output stream to look something like this:

```
Z,102,Y,101,randomName1,A,11,B,12,C,13,randomName2,A,21,B,22,C,23,...
.
.
.
```

Thanks for your help.

-

### ----------------- 3/23/16 update below --------------

Again, thanks for the help.  Here's what I finally came up with.  It does what I need:

```
import json

with open('MyFile.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

for record in data:
    print record['Z'],record['Y']
    for randomName in record['X']:
        print randomName, randomName['A'], randomName['B'],randomName['C']
```

...

Comment: Thank you Padraic and E.Gordon.  Your posts were very helpful.  I thought that I could figure things out from there, but in trying to make my original post as concise as possible I'm afraid I over-simplified the JSON data example.  I edited my original post to add the new info.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can print the items in the dicts:

```
js = [{u'randomName1': {u'A': 16,u'B': 20,u'C': 71},u'randomName2': {u'A': 12,u'B': 17,u'C': 47}}]


for dct in js:
    for k, v in dct.items():
        print(k, v)
```

Which gives you the key/inner dict pairings:

```
randomName1 {'B': 20, 'A': 16, 'C': 71}
randomName2 {'B': 17, 'A': 12, 'C': 47}
```

If you want the values from the inner dicts you can add another loop

```
for dct in js:
    for k1, d in dct.items():
        print(k1)
        for k2,v in d.items():
            print(k2,v)
```

Which will give you:

```
randomName1
A 16
B 20
C 71
randomName2
A 12
B 17
C 47
```

If you have arbitrary levels of nesting we will have to do it recursively.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `for element in list` construct to loop over all the elements in a list, [without having to know its length](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).

The [iteritems()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) dictionary method provides a convenient way to get the key-value pairs from a dictionary, again without needing to know how many there are or what the keys are called.

For example:

```
import json   

with open('MyFile.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)    

for element in data:
    for name, values in element.iteritems():
        print("%s has A=%d, B=%d and C=%d" % (name, 
                                              values["A"], 
                                              values["B"], 
                                              values["C"]))
```